# Function of bounded variation as measure

Tags: measure-theory, analytic-geometry, bounded-variation, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\phi: [0,1] \to R$ be a function of bounded variation that jumps at one point $x=1/2.$ I know that by the structure theorem
$D\phi= \nabla \phi L^1 +  D^c \phi+( \phi(x^+) - \phi(x^-))\delta_x.$

Now I want to integrate a BV function $\psi $ that jumps also at $x=1/2$ with respect to the measure $D\phi.$ What confuses me is the jump part of the measure. If $\psi$ was continuous I would get $( \phi(x^+) - \phi(x^-))\psi(1/2) $ but $\psi$ here is a BV function so it is defined as a class of functions!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The question is based on a misunderstanding: even if $\psi\in\mathrm{BV}([{0,1}])$ *it is nevertheless a function*, not a class. It can be chosen as the representative of a given class in $\mathrm{BV}([{0,1}])$, and as such *its pointwise structure is irrelevant* (as long as it is relevant only on a set of measure zero), *from the point of view of the calculation of the associated Radon measure, but not when you use it for doing other operations*. The exact knowledge of $\psi$ allows in principle to integrate it respect to the Radon measure generated by another $\phi\in\mathrm{BV}([{0,1}])$ (which can be determined by using *any* function in the same equivalence class in $\mathrm{BV}$) by using the standard formula
$$
\int\limits_{[0,1]}\psi \mathrm{d}(D\phi)=\int\limits_{[0,1]}\psi\nabla\phi\mathrm{d}\mu_L+\int\limits_{[0,1]}\psi \mathrm{d}(D^c\phi)+\left(\phi(x^+) - \phi(x^-)\right)\psi(x)\quad x=\frac{1}{2} \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
where $\mu_L$ is the standard Lebesgue measure.

It is nevertheless true that, if you only know that $\psi$ is a function of bounded variation you cannot evaluate \eqref{1}, but this happens in every case when the knowledge of a property of a function is not equivalent to the knowledge of the property needed to perform a particular operation. In sum, *to integrate a function respect to a given general Radon measure you should know its values on the singular set*.