# Lebesgue-Stieltjes Integral of Singleton

Tags: analysis, continuity, lebesgue-integral, stieltjes-integral

I have two functions $f,g\in\textit{BV}(K,\mathbb R)$, where $\textit{BV}(K,\mathbb R)$ is the set of all functions mapping $K\subset\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ that are of bounded variation. The function $f$ is, in addition, bounded and continuous except at a countable set $D\subset K$. I have to compute the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral $$\int_K f\,\mathrm dg.$$
**Question**: Is the following manipulation valid: $$\int_Kf\,\mathrm dg = \int_{K\setminus D}f\,\mathrm dg + \int_Df\,\mathrm dg.$$
I believe yes, as we could define a measure $\mu$ that satisfies $\mu((a,b]) = g(b) - g(a-)$ for all left-half open intervals $(a,b]$. Then $$\int_Kf\,\mathrm dg = \int_Kf\,\mathrm d\mu$$ and a basic property of Lebesgue integrals yields $$\int_Kf,\mathrm d\mu = \int_Af\,\mathrm d\mu + \int_Bf\,\mathrm d\mu,$$ where $A\cup B = K$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Using this property again and again should yield $$\int_{D}f\,\mathrm dg = \sum_{d\in D}\int_{\{d\}} f\,\mathrm dg$$
(see [Prove the Countable additivity of Lebesgue Integral.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668958/prove-the-countable-additivity-of-lebesgue-integral)). This brings me to the question stated in the title. For the usual Lebesgue measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb R$ we have that $$\int_{\{d\}}f\,\mathrm d\nu = 0.$$ But since the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure is slightly different, the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral of a point is not necessarily zero. Eventually, I am interested in bounded the integral by $$\int_{\{d\}}f\,\mathrm dg \leq \sup_{x\in K}\vert f(x)\vert (g(d) - g(d-)).$$ Is my reasoning correct? In particular, is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral of a signle point well-defined?

Comment: Is this really this complicated? To get the final bound you search for, wouldn't it suffice to notice that $f$ is constant on $\{d\}$? Then $$\int_{\{d\}}f\,dg=f(d)\int_{\{d\}}1\,dg=f(d)(g(d)-g(d-)).$$ Then the inequality follows as $f(d)\le \sup_{x\in K} f(x) \le \sup_{x\in K}\vert f(x)\vert$. Am I missing something?

Comment: As stated by @C.Brendel in [his comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796053/lebesgue-stieltjes-integral-of-singleton#comment10319898_4796053), if you define $\textit{BV}$-functions in one variable [in the classical way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#BV_functions_of_one_variable), there is no difficulty as these functions are bounded *tout court*. On the other hand, if you define them by using the $n$-dimensional definition for $n=1$, [far worser things may happen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2811330/function-of-bounded-variation-as-measure).

Comment: Thank you all for your replys. If I understand this correctly, the issue arises from the fact that $f$ may be unbounded at the discontinuity $d$, right?